# Cannot login to Opencart Admin after Enabling SSL

Tags: ssl, authentication, admin

I have enabled ssl for my opencart store but after enabling ssl,i am unable to login to admin section.I have also reversed the changes made in the config and admin folder but still unable to login.Please advise

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

have you played around with your .htaccess? if not you probably still have the https:// prefix to your urls on your admin. you should however be able to login 
what browser are you using and how are you accessing your admin (via what url).

Answer (score 0):

Create a file .htaccess on admin folder with the content: "RewriteBase /" only.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to check your admin config file in `admin/config.php`: both `HTTPS_CATALOG` and `HTTPS_SERVER` variables should point to your secure URL.

Comment: Yes it was done..Sorry not logged in for a long time